# Fields Integer as String, how can do? Php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i need change all fields integer to string, how can do? i am using php, laravel, mysql.

The reason is because i need to set the value from the database in 
 input select, to that I am using angularjs, I know that there are a lots of ways to resolve that. But I have a form with 2.5k lines and almost 40 input select so I need a fix easy.

Comment: $protected casts in laravel Model maybe?

Comment: yeah but this is not easy because i need casts a lots of fields, i reading something about setting in mysql to return all fields interger as string.

Comment: in the model constructor add a foreach on the attributes and if they are no string, then convert them to string

Comment: how can do that?

Comment: What problems are you getting on the front end that requires this?

Comment: the input select is empty, but de ng-model have the value from data base

Comment: but laravel already convert everything to string...

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, as a new user I suggest reading what questions are and are not appropriate for the site (Link is to what not to with this being your first question): https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: ok but how can do that with laravel if i have 24 models with more of 40 fields for every model?

Answer (score 0):

PHP will interpret the variable as the type you use it as.  If you append a number to a string, it becomes a string.

```
$var = 12;
var_dump($var); // I am an integer
var_dump("{$var}"); // I am a string
```